# XSLT 2 processor for Postgres 9.4.1

Tags: postgresql, xslt-2.0, libxslt

I have a requirement to use XSLT 2 for processing XML and convert them to XSL FO for printing downloadable catalogs. I use libxslt and this supports only XSLT 2. Googling for XSLT 2 processors did not provide any open source version for trial. Any suggestions?

Comment: And how is this related to Postgres? Do you want to do the XSLT through SQL functions?

Comment: Yes. The XSLT requests will fire from website through a DB function. I look for something like libxslt on Postgres which supports XSLT 2.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/). You need to install [PL/Java](https://github.com/tada/pljava) first.